# Select random Enumeration by value

Tags: scala, enumeration

So i have this `Enumeration`:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val a = Value(0, "Valid")
  val b = Value(1, "Valid")
  val c = Value(2, "Not Valid")
  val d = Value(3, "Not Valid")
}
```

This `Enumeration` contains 2 types: `Valid` and `Not valid`.
Is it possible to select random `MyEnum` by value ?

For example i want to select a random `MyEnum` that is `Valid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when Yuval answer is correct and the solution will work, using `Enumeration` for encoding additional property is not recommended. By using `name` field for encoding the type as `"Valid"` or `"Not Valid"` (or any other classification) of your `Value`s you are loosing build in ability of `Enumeration` class to reconstruct the enum value instances from `String` via `.withName` method:

```
// result will be always `a` for "Valid" and `b` for "Not Valid"
// it will throw an NoSuchElementException for any other string
MyEnum.withName(someString)
```

To put it simple when you are simply misusing `name` field for classification of your enum value instances. If this is not a problem in your code you're a lucky guy, but anyway document the misuse very precisely.

`Enumeration` was intended to express simple values, which have an index and can have nice human readable name. That's it, no more, no less.

Rule of thumb is, that when you have an enum which needs another fields it is better to model that using sealed hierarchy of `case objects` or `case classes`. Something like that (just an example for your particular case):

```
// Hierarchy is sealed, thus you will get can pattern match with check for exhaustiveness
sealed trait MyEnum {
  def id: Int
  def name: String
  def valid: Boolean
}
// Helper case class, which allows to not define
private case class Value(id: Int, name: String, valid: Boolean) extends MyEnum

object MyEnum {  
  // Your values
  val A: MyEnum = Value(0, "My A", true)
  val B: MyEnum = Value(1, "My B", true)
  val C: MyEnum = Value(0, "My A", false)
  val D: MyEnum = Value(1, "My B", false)

  // Re-implementation of methods contained in Enumeration, pick what you need
  val values: Seq[MyEnum] = Seq(A, B, C, D)
  // You can implement your own semantics, e.g. no Exception rather Option
  def withName(name: String): Option[MyEnum] = values.find( _.name == name )

  // Methods already for your example
  val valids: Seq[MyEnum] = values.filter( _.valid )
  // Or with randomization build in to enum
  def randomValid: MyEnum = valids(util.Random.nextInt(valids.length))
}
```

In addition you will get more type safety:

```
// More type safety, fn simple does not compile
def fn(value: MyEnum) = value match {
  case MyEnum.A => true
}

<console>:14: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Value(_, _, _)
       def fn(value: MyEnum) = value match {
                               ^
fn: (value: MyEnum)Boolean
```

Your milage may vary, because possibilities for writing an enum in Scala are almost endless :) In my example I'm showing only one of many possible implementations. If you have many values above mentioned approach can be impractical.

To know more about drawbacks of using `Enumeration` see ["Scala Enumerations"](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html) blog post. **Beware that solution in the end of article is not silver bullet and has problems with pattern matching exhaustiveness checking as `Enumeration` does.**

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
val valids = MyEnum.values.filter { _.toString.equalsIgnoreCase("Valid") }.toSeq
val selected = valids(util.Random.nextInt(valids.length))

println(s"Selected $selected with id: ${selected.id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scala Random:

```
scala.util.Random.shuffle(MyEnum.values.toList).find(_.toString.equalsIgnoreCase("Valid"))
```

and it will return an Option